# sunspot rails, adding extra param to search block fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot, sunspot-solr

Trying to implement search with Sunspot Gem wich is using Solr.Fulltext search works fine however adding extra search params returning zero results. Red all docs but to no avail I dont see my error, if any in below code. Any advise on how to fix this? I RE-indexed existing records.

ProfilesController#index

```
@search = Profile.search do

      fulltext params[:search]

      if params[:search].present?
        fulltext params[:description] do
          highlight :description
        end
      end

      if params[:gender].present?
        with :gender
      end
      paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    end

    @profiles = @search.results
```

profiles.rb model

```
searchable do
    text :description
    string :gender 
end
```

My search form:

```
= simple_form_for profiles_path, :method => :get  do |f|

  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]  << this works
  = text_field_tag :gender, params[:gender]  << adding this line returns 0 result
```

Params gender can be "male" or "female" without quotes this param is also submitted by the form.

Comment: Did you re-index your objects?
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex

Comment: Forgot to mention, yes I did re-index all still to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if params[:gender].present?
      with :gender,  params[:gender]
  end
```

and use select tag

```
<%= select_tag 'gender', options_for_select([['Male', 'male'], ['Female', 'female']]), :prompt => 'Select Gender' %>`
```

Comment: Did not work. I cleaned all my form just leaving 2 options, 1 for full text search and 1 for the gender removed all the other search options from block also. Seems my form is invalid, if i just do with :gender, "male" it works fine. No idea exactly whats going wrong though

Comment: When indexing are they 1/0 or male/female.

Comment: There are males and females I bugged the issue down to a {:params=>"[[\"Male\", :male], [\"Female\", :female]]"} being send in params[:gender] and not only the item selected, how would i get just "male" or "female" depending on what was selected?

Comment: Use select_tag <%= select_tag 'gender', options_for_select([['Male', 'male'], ['Female', 'female']]), :prompt => 'Select Gender'  %>                 Can you also verify the what is stored in that particular table for this gender field

Comment: DeatHammer: that did it indeed! Found out it passed the complete selection box and found the select tag but you where first ;) Only problem is Im using code like this "  = f.select  :gender, gender,
              :prompt => t(:choose, :scope => :forms),
              :required => false
" Where Gender is a helper function to translate the strings, Could we work around that? Im also using simple_form seems using the helper method for select_tag isnt supported I guess I have to rewrite it to support select_tag or find a workaround. But this issue is in itself solved, thx! Caused some headache ;)

Comment: This finally did the trick:   = select_tag 'gender', options_for_select(gender),  :prompt => t(:choose, :scope => :forms)
I update answer as solution, can you add the solution from 2 comments above to the answer? big thx!!